# Cannot load dll: C:\...\libmysql.dll on Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: windows, windows-10, mysql

I recently had a massive computer crash and had to reinstall Windows entirely.  During this process, my old installation was renamed as `Windows.old`.  I am reinstalling some applications including Dev Desktop which includes a MySQL database server.  However, when I try to launch it after installation, (which gives me no problems) I get the above error.

Could this somehow (I don't know how, I'm not running anything from it) be related to the previous installation of this same piece of software on the drive?

What could be causing this? How do I resolve it? I'm not really familiar with Windows log files (most of my development and sysadmin stuff is done on Linux machines) - where can I go to troubleshoot this?

The exact location of the DLLs:

C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\mysql\lib

MySQL is installed as part of the install process for the application.

Comment: Nevermind, got it working, it needed the Visual Studio 2010 package.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL was installed correctly, however it couldn't run due to a DLL missing from the VS 2010 package.

Reinstalling VS2010 helped get it working again.

Comment: Your answer is more of a comment if more instruction was added this could change.("if you reinstalled or if you checked for missing dll's, etc. please take a couple of minutes and read:- http://superuser.com/help .Answering: http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: The solution for me was installing the 32 bit version of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 runtimes.